# standard-version - How to bump back to previous version?

Tags: git, npm

I accidentally used `npm run release:patch` command from [standard-version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard-version) where I shouldn't.

Is there a way to return to the previous bumped version?

Comment: I noticed this wasn't an `npm` problem, but a `git` one. I had to delete the `git tag` before rebumping it with that name, like this:
1) `git tag -l` (this gives you the list of all the git tags available)
2) `git tag -d <name>` (this deletes said name)

Answer (score 0):

You can unpublish the version you have published. Here is the official [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/unpublishing-packages-from-the-registry). You can also consider deprecating it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).